# Sound not working

Tags: sound

I am new to ubuntu, but really enjoy it.  I do have one issue with setting it up on my computer.  It is a GoBook XR-1 and everything works perfectly except there is no sound.  I've searched and tried everything that I can think of, even uninstalling ubuntu and trying Windows to see if the speakers worked.  I found out that it wasn't the speakers or any hardware issues.  I tried to download the Realtek drivers, but still no success.

Comment: First of all, does you Ubuntu at least see audio card? In System Settings -Sound is it listed or not?

Comment: Could you **edit your question** and provide more details? Like the Sound Card you are using, with `lspci -nnk | grep -A5 Audio`? The output of `pulseaudio --check`, `pulseaudio --dump-conf`, `amixer -c 0`, `pacmd dump-volumes` and `pactl info`.

Answer (score 1):

The solution for this model of laptop is to block the snd_hda_codecs from being loaded, then manually load and unload the snd_hda_realtek codec.

In the file /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf :

```
blacklist snd_hda_codec
blacklist snd_hda_codec_si3054
blacklist snd_hda_codec_realtek
```

In the file /etc/rc.local :

```
modprobe snd_hda_codec_realtek
rmmod snd_hda_intel
modprobe snd_hda_intel
rmmod snd_hda_intel
rmmod snd_hda_codec_realtek
modprobe snd_hda_intel
```

I can hardly believe this works, but it does!

Answer (score 0):

Update Ubuntu. That may fix the issue. If you still have the issue, run:

```bash
killall pulseaudio; rm -r ~/.pulse*
```

If that did not help, run:

```bash
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-audio-dev/ppa; sudo apt-get update;sudo apt-get dist-upgrade; sudo apt-get install pavucontrol linux-sound-base alsa-base alsa-utils gdm ubuntu-desktop  linux-image-`uname -r` libasound2; sudo apt-get -y --reinstall install linux-sound-base alsa-base alsa-utils gdm ubuntu-desktop  linux-image-`uname -r` libasound2; killall pulseaudio; rm -r ~/.pulse*; sudo usermod -aG `cat /etc/group | grep -e '^pulse:' -e '^audio:' -e '^pulse-access:' -e '^pulse-rt:' -e '^video:' | awk -F: '{print $1}' | tr '\n' ',' | sed 's:,$::g'` `whoami`
```

After that, reboot. If it did not help, post the output of this command:

```bash
wget -O alsa-info.sh http://www.alsa-project.org/alsa-info.sh && chmod +x ./alsa-info.sh && ./alsa-info.sh
```

Comment: Follow the instructions [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SoundTroubleshootingProcedure) for a full guide for troubleshooting sound.